# What is the value if you shift beyond the last element of an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, null, shift, undef

In this piece of code, shift is used twice, even though the method only takes one parameter:

```
sub regexVerify ($)
{
   my $re = shift;

   return sub
   {
      local $_ = shift;
      m/$re/ ? $_ : undef;
   };
}
```

What does this make the value of local $_, once shift is used again?  I was (perhaps naively) assuming that shifting into nothingness would result in undef.  But if that were true, this line has no meaning, right?:

```
m/$re/ ? $_ : undef;
```

The above sub is called like:

```
regexVerify (qr/^([a-z].*)?$/i);
```

Comment: The answer to your title question is: `undef`.

Answer (score 2):

The second `shift` is inside the inner `sub` declaration. That scope will have an entirely new `@_` to work with, which won't have anything to do with the `@_` passed to the outer subroutine.

`regexVerify` is a subroutine that returns another subroutine. Presumably you would later invoke that subroutine with an argument:

```
my $func = regexVerify(qr/^([a-z].*)?$/i);
# $func is now a "code reference" or "anonymous subroutine"

...

if ($func->($foo)) {    # invoke the subroutine stored in $func with arg ($foo)
    print "$foo is verified.\n";
} else {
    print "$foo is not verified!\n";
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't get it --- if the inner sub takes no parameters, what is local $_ being initialized as, if not undef?

Comment: @CptSupermrkt The inner sub *does* take parameters, re-read mob's answer. `regexVerify` returns a sub, which is then invoked like `$func->($This_Is_A_Parameter)`!

Comment: It does take a parameter, `$foo` in the example.

Answer (score 2):

`local $_ = shift;` doesn't get executed until you make call to anonymous function. ie

```
my $anon_func = regexVerify (qr/^([a-z].*)?$/i);

# NOW sending arguments in @_ for local $_ = shift;
print $anon_func->("some string");
```